# Maya ImportError: 'No module named util' after running Python Script in PyCharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm, maya

I am trying to run a 'main.py' file in Maya which imports various scripts located in a folder named 'util'. However I always get '# ImportError: No module named util #' in Maya.

The structure is as follows:

folder named rigging_script :

```
.idea
util
    ├──__init__.py
    ├──createControls.py
    ├──...
git
Main.py
README.md
```

The main.py starts as follows:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/Francis/PycharmProjects/rigging_script/util')
from util import globalVariables
```

The connection with maya works, Note that I got it to work on my private Laptop (with a different path of course).
I already tried to mark the util folder as source, or to check and uncheck 'Add content roots to PYTHONPATH' and 'Add source roots to PYTHONPATH'.

Help would be really appreciated.

[Main folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYY92.png)

[util folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlOZf.png)

[pycharm Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap5Uc.png)

[Main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2MB4.png)

**EDIT**

I got it to work for a short amount of time with a src folder with main.py and util inside but the same issue as before happenend when I restarted.

Comment: Looks like your path is one level too deep. If you want to be able to import the module named `util`, you need to add its parent to `sys.path` (eg C:/Users/Francis/PycharmProjects/rigging_script)

Comment: Thank you, that was it! what a dumb mistake on my part, but oh well.